# uploading multiple files on carrierwave (implementing arrays) while using sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, carrierwave

I'm building a web-app using ruby on rails `(4.2.5)`,

I need the user to be able to upload multiple files as attachments when creating an object **(called "Request" in this case**).

I was able to implement **carrierwave (0.9)** and users can upload a file to each request, but turns out that the multiple files functionality requires an array-type column, which is not available as a datatype in the SQLite database which I am using.

From the above things, I think it seems that you can use JSON to do that, but I don't know how that works.

I would like to know how I can work around this problem and allow the user to upload multiple files to the request, even if I should use an entirely different method.

Thank you

Comment: You can have the name of the input field like this: `<input type="file" size="10" multiple="true" name="attachments[]">`, and then in controller save each image while looping over `params[:]attachments]`. I hope you want to save each image as a record in db.

Comment: @Sahil Thank you very much ! I created a table for the images that belongs to requests, and inside the create method in the requests controller, I loop over them like so : `params[:attachments].each do | attch |  
      @img = Image.new(:img_id => @req.req_id, :attachment => attch)  
      @img.save  
    end `   Thanks again !

Comment: Great! So its working now.